# Access string from ReadString

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I can't seem to be able to access a string that I'm reading, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
.data
    ans    BYTE    2    DUP(?)

.code

main proc
    call    read
    exit
main endp    

read proc
    mov     edx, OFFSET ans
    mov     ecx, 1
    call    ReadString
    mov     edx, OFFSET ans
    call    WriteString
read endp
```

This prints out nothing.  How can I access `ans`?  This seems like it should be really easy, but I can't figure out how to print `ans`.

Comment: You don't seem to be [using `ReadString` correctly](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/readstring.htm) (you didn't set up `ecx`). Also, you should probably make `ans` bigger than just one byte.

Comment: @Michael I adjusted my code to reflect those changes, but I'm still running into the same problem.  I've edited my code, is there still something wrong with it?